# KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to plot the ROC curve for decision tree classifier. My code is raising `key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex` error.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

# Load the Fake news dataset
df_fake = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Downloads/Fake.csv")

# Load the True news dataset
df_true = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Downloads/True.csv")

# Set fake as 1 and true as 0
df_true["class"] = 0
df_fake["class"] = 1

# Concatenate true and fake datasets
df = pd.concat([df_fake, df_true])

# Sanity check
print(f'N rows={len(df)}, M columns={len(df.columns)}')
df.head()
```

Dataframe

```
df.head()
```

|  | title | text | subject | date | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Donald Trump Sends Out Embarrassing New Year’... | Donald Trump just couldn t wish all Americans ... | News | December 31, 2017 | 1 |
| 1 | Drunk Bragging Trump Staffer Started Russian ... | House Intelligence Committee Chairman Devin Nu... | News | December 31, 2017 | 1 |
| 2 | Sheriff David Clarke Becomes An Internet Joke... | On Friday, it was revealed that former Milwauk... | News | December 31, 2017 | 1 |
| 3 | Trump Is So Obsessed He Even Has Obama’s Name... | On Christmas day, Donald Trump announced that ... | News | December 31, 2017 | 1 |
| 4 | Pope Francis Just Called Out Donald Trump Dur... | Pope Francis used his annual Christmas Day mes... | News | December 31, 2017 | 1 |

```
# Extract title column in Tf-IDf
X = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', max_features=50).fit_transform(df['title'])
N, M = X.shape

# Dataframe info
y = df["class"]

# Divide dataset into a separate training dataset (80%) and test dataset (20%)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, stratify=y, random_state=1)

# Baseline classification
dummy_clf = DummyClassifier(strategy="most_frequent")
dummy_clf.fit(X, y)
dummy_clf.predict(X)
dummy_clf.score(X, y)


def plot_roc(y_score):
    fpr = {}
    tpr = {}
    roc_auc = {}
    for i in range(M):
        fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
        roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

    # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
    fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
    roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])

    return roc_auc[1]


# Decision tree using the "gini" criterion
dt_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini", random_state=0)
dt_gini_score = dt_gini.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
plot_roc(dt_gini_score)
```

Traceback

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Applied ML/Mod4.py", line 62, in
> <module>
>     plot_roc(dt_gini_score)   File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Applied ML/Mod4.py", line 49, in
> plot_roc
>     fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Applied
> ML\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 966, in
> __getitem__
>     return self._get_with(key)   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Applied
> ML\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 981, in
> _get_with
>     return self._get_values_tuple(key)   File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Applied
> ML\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1016, in
> _get_values_tuple
>     raise KeyError("key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex") KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You can try this instead of manually filling `roc_auc` with a loop. 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html

Comment: @tanmay2893 `dt_gini = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini", random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
dt_gini_score = roc_auc_score(y_test, dt_gini)
plot_roc(dt_gini_score)` still raises `'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'` error.

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite the `plot_roc` function like so (I tryed it with the toy dataset provided in the question) :

```py
from sklearn import metrics
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def plot_roc(y_test, y_score):

    fpr = dict()
    tpr = dict()
    roc_auc = dict()
    
    # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
    fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
    roc_auc["micro"] = metrics.auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
    plt.figure()
    lw = 2
    plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], color='darkorange',
             lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc["micro"])
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
    plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
    plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic example')
    plt.legend(loc="lower right")
    plt.show()
```

And we call it that way :

```py
plot_roc(y_test, dt_gini_score)
```

To get the expected plot.